# How to unescape HTML in Nokogiri Ruby, so & remains & and not &amp;

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a title `doc.at('head/title').inner_html` that comes out `&amp;` and it should be `&`.

My original document is:

```
<head><title>Foo & Bar</title></head>
```

but in comes out as the following:

```
>> doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(file, nil, "UTF-8")
>> doc.at('head/title')
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x..fdb851bea name="title" children=#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x..fdb850808 "Foo & Bar">>
>> doc.at('head/title').inner_html
=> "Foo &amp; Bar"
```

I don't want to use Iconv or CGI like:

```
>> require 'cgi'
>> CGI.unescapeHTML(doc.at('head/title').inner_html)
=> "Foo & Bar"
```

that is ugly and inconvenient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `content` instead of `inner_html` to get the content as plain text instead of (X)HTML.

```
irb(main):011:0> doc.at('head/title').content
=> "Foo & Bar"
```